# UILabel scroll possible?

Tags: objective-c

I've got a UILabel whit a bunch of text but the text is stopping after xx lines. My question: 
Can i connect a scroll to a UILabel OR can i connect it to a textview?

What is the best way to display a large text (text = from JSON feed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UITextView is scrollable and, if you'd like it to act more like a label, you can turn off editing.

Comment: But how can i connect it with a IBOutlet so the data is displaying?

Comment: make a new IBOutlet for your UITextView. And then add the text in the same way you did it with your label before..

Comment: Yes thanks! Got it: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView* textView;